# Run Script in background of codeigneitor?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a module in ci named "Incentive". i have wrote function in controller to run a php script in background.but it doesnt working,

Here is my function in Controller

```
function backgroundrun(){

    echo "working";
    $command = shell_exec("localhost/new/index.php?module=incentive&view=allIncentive&date=2016-02-29  > /dev/null & echo $!");
    echo $out = exec( $command);
    echo "here";
}
```

here is the url of the script that i want to run

`localhost/new/index.php?module=incentive&view=allIncentive&date=2016-03-29`

Comment: i think this will help `echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/new/index.php?module=incentive&view=allIncentive&date=2016-03-29");`

Answer (score 0):

**curl**: is a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP). The command is designed to work without user interaction.

For reference see this link - https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

In the *nix based system, run this command in the terminal to check curl is installed or not.

```
# which curl
```

This will return output like this if it's installed.

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

So you can use this script to perform your job.

```
$command = shell_exec("curl http://127.0.0.1/new/index.php?module=incentive&view=allIncentive&date=2016-02-29  > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

use of `localhost` in script will return such type of error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost
```

Hope this will help you !!